# Command line games

Tags: server, command-line, games

Does anyone know if there are games for Ubuntu server (like tetris, etc...)?

I know that servers aren't meant for playing games, but sometimes it would be nice to have a little fun . . . not only work on them :)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can install the package [bsdgames](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/bsdgames) to get a collection of games, then there is the excellent NetHack and the fast paced, all action, all the time, gravity defying, "moonbuggy".

here is a list of games provided by the bsdgames package to get you going:

- adventure
- arithmetic
- atc
- backgammon
- battlestar
- bcd
- boggle
- caesar
- canfield
- cfscores
- countmail
- cribbage
- dab
- go-fish
- gomoku
- hack
- hangman
- hunt
- mille
- monop
- morse
- number
- phantasia
- pig
- pom
- ppt
- primes
- quiz
- rain
- random
- robots
- rot13
- sail
- snake
- snscore
- teachgammon
- tetris-bsd
- trek
- wargames
- worm
- worms
- wtf
- wump

Answer (score 9):

I "played" with **vimtutor**. I know it is not the exact answer to your question but I treated as a get to next level game, and won in productivity...

Answer (score 8):

Sure! You should try Nethack.

Just install the package nethack-console ( *sudo apt-get install nethack-console* ) and enjoy.

From wikipedia:

> NetHack is a single-player roguelike
>   video game originally released in
>   1987. It is a descendant of an earlier game called Hack (1985), which is a
>   descendant of Rogue (1980).[2] Salon
>   describes it as "one of the finest
>   gaming experiences the computing world
>   has to offer."

Answer (score 7):

Here is an oldie but a goodie - space invaders! (sudo apt-get install ninvaders)

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Install Emacs, there is a *terminal only* package available for servers too. Call emacs into a terminal. Inside it, hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> and write `tetris`. To quit tetris, hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> then <kbd>k</kbd> then <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
 Have fun!

[image]

For a list of all games available for emacs, visit [here](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/CategoryGames).

Answer (score 5):

Or play the popular [2048](http://www.leaseweblabs.com/2014/03/text-mode-2048-game-c-algorithm-explained/) game from the command line.

To install:

```
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mevdschee/2048.c/master/2048.c
gcc -o 2048 2048.c
```

To play the game:

```
./2048
```

[github](https://github.com/mevdschee/2048.c)

Answer (score 4):

**Overkill** is a death-match game full of blood which runs within the terminal. This game can only be run over a network against multiple players.

to install the game: `sudo apt-get install overkill`

to run the game: `xoverkill`

---

**Dungeon Crawl**
[here.](http://crawl-ref.sourceforge.net/) It is a roguelike adventure through dungeons filled with dangerous monsters in a quest to find the mystifyingly fabulous Orb of Zot.

Answer (score 4):

What about a MMORPG on Command line?

Other intelligent people playing with you and chatting in a nice community?

Just run:

```
telnet Sverige.freeshell.org 4000
```

Answer (score 3):

Another addition: [vitetris](http://victornils.net/tetris/) is a multiplayer, network-enabled tetris clone. It even has joystick support, if you so desire.

Answer (score 2):

There is `typespeed` on ubuntu where you has to type random unix commands. This way you will learn unix commands. 
Below is screenshot of how it looks[image: typespeed screenshot]

you can install it using
`sudo apt-get install typespeed`